# Magento 1.6 - Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm having an issue with my Magento install where it won't display any shipping methods on checkout.  The weird thing is that the quote functionality in the cart works fine.  Looking at the UPS log, I can see that it gets the shipping info fine from UPS during checkout, but it's just breaking down somewhere along the line and not displaying it.  The entry for this checkout in the UPS log is [here](http://pastebin.com/cRWRiEvv)

I also have flat-rate shipping enabled, and that won't show up either.  Any thoughts?  This may or may not make a difference, but I have the multi-warehouse extension installed as well.  If you need more inform

Comment: Did you try it with the extension not installed?

Comment: Yeah.  It works fine with the extension uninstalled.  Unfortunately the company that created the plugin doesn't provide much support.  I can always dive in and try to fix it myself, but I was hoping someone may have had similar experiences.